# Jquery drag n drop file loading progress

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building file uploading/drag and drop.
I used this jquery plugin: https://github.com/jaysalvat/ezdz
Dnd is working well, but I just wanted to upload huge size of the file, over 1GB.
When I drag and drop the file into dropzone, it always takes too long time to load the file in the browser(not upload - didn't click "upload" button. Just loading to the browser to load that file.)

So, I just wanted to check this progress(loading file to the browser). This is not checking uploading progress, I think this is something different with checking file uploading progress.
Is there any solution to check this?

Comment: I don't see any information about that plugin supporting progress info. [this one does tho](https://github.com/Pamblam/fileUpload) and it's easy to use.

Comment: Thanks @Occam'sRazor I will try to use it.

Comment: Just in case you have to get down into the details to solve this, there's probably a `FileReader` involved in this DND suport somewhere, and `FileReader` does have an `onprogress` callback: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader